Creating React dropdown where only icon shows when unopened
Im creating this to do list in React + JS, and ran into a problem where i want to change Type of status dropdown so you only have an icon of the selected value when dropdown is unopened. when opened. i want all other values to have text + icon. like this: 
Right now i cannot get it so it just shows the icon at all times. this is the code of the Component + items array. anyone that has any idea, would be appreciated
const items = [
          {id: 1, type: "in_review", name: "In Review", icon: ''},
          {id: 2, type: "in_progress", name: "In Progress", icon: ''},
          {id: 3, type: "todo", name: "Todo", icon: ""},
          {id: 4, type: "done", name: "Done", icon: "☑️"},
          {id: 5, type: "canceled", name: "Canceled", icon: ""}

      ]

Component:
import React from 'react';

function TypeSelector({ option, handleOptionChange, items }) {
    return (
        <select value={option.type} onChange={handleOptionChange}>
            {items.map((item) => (
                <option key={item.id} value={item.type}>
                    {item.icon} {item.name}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
}

export default TypeSelector;


Right now it works as in it shows it like this: 
And i want the top value, which is the only one showing when not opening the dropdown., to be just the icon.

Is it required to use  tag? You could create a button that displays an emoji,
and on click it shows a dropdown, where you select the option. Also it could be a bit challenging to style  due to different browser compatibilities

@vljs Ahh you are right that'd be way easier, thanks for the tip. using select only makes it a lot more difficult.
